# GT-I9506 / Fastboot

Tags: android, adb

In order to install Ubuntu on my Android Device I need to do some configuration before, I use Ubuntu on my Machine, I installed adb and fastboot installed with repository, I'm actually installing every Android SDK tools, in order to fix by problems.

I would like in the bootloader of my device execute this command from my machine :

```
sudo fastboot oem unlock
```

but the command give to me this ;

```
root@ixtreme-M5850:/home/axel# sudo fastboot oem unlock
< waiting for device >
```

But never end...

adb commands work on my devices;

Informations about my devices :

```
GT-I9506
Version : 6.0.1
Kernel : 3.4.111-arte97-11.3
SELinux : Permissif
```

I already tried to change the version of my devices, Lineage OS, REMIX N, etc...

thanks !

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: That's because adb and fastboot are different protocols and devices use different USB identifiers for that. It also depends on how you installed both tools. Did you do it through the Ubuntu repositories? On which version exactly? Or did you use the Android SDK instead? Also CyanogenMod is obsolete now, please don't run unpatched software. Use Lineage if possible.